# $C(T) =l^{\infty}, C_0(T) = c_0, C_c(T) = c_{00}$, where $C(T), C_0(T), C_c(T) $

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

When $T$ is the set of natural numbers with usual Euclidean metric (equivalent to discrete
metric on $\mathbb{N}$) then 
$C(T) =l^{\infty},  C_0(T) = c_0, C_c(T) = c_{00}$, where $C(T),  C_0(T),  C_c(T) $ means continuous function on $T$, continuous function vanishing at zero, continuous function with compact support respectively.

How can I identify?I tried but not getting any clue. Please help.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete with the Euclidean metric is discrete. Therefore, $C(\mathbb{N})$ consists of all the functions, not only the bounded ones.

Comment: How can i do the math here?@SphericalTriangle